# Echo shell command within vim

Tags: vim

I am writing some map commands that run external commands.  For example, I may have the following map command to compile the working project.

```
nnoremap <F5> :!mvn compile test<CR>
```

However, when vim switches to a shell, it's not clear what command is running.  Is there a way for the command to show up on the shell, short of echoing it?  It seems tedious to need to write the following each time, but it would do what I want.

```
nnoremap <F5> :!echo "mvn compile test"<CR>:!mvn compile test<CR>
```

Comment: use nnoremap is a better idea

Comment: I understand why the first 'n' is important, by why is 'nore' so important?  Does it give an error if <F5> is already mapped?

Comment: http://stevelosh.com/blog/2011/09/writing-vim-plugins/#imap-and-nmap-are-pure-evil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your external command processor is a UNIX style shell, it has an echo feature, and you need only to pass the x option to it:

```
map <F5> :!sh -xc 'mvn compile test'<CR>
```